# How to lock down a web application for paying customers only with a key?

Tags: web-applications

There are some apps which when bought make you enter a secret key of some sort to prove you bought the thing. Cool, but how is that done? Not for hacking, but out of curiosity. Does it even work?

Say for example,

1. a fictional ACME company developed the AcmeSuperDuperSlider.
2. Which one buys and uses on 1 domain.

How does the app know when it is used on a different domain? Web Services?

I may need to lock something down before deployment so I'm looking for advice.

Comment: I removed the [javascript] tag because this has nothing to do with JS. Does that contradict your intention?

Comment: @NiklasB. I dont think so. I approached it from a javascript (widget) perspective, but the answer appears not to include JS at all. Good call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is never done in JavaScript, as the source isn't hidden from the user.

You'd have to use some sort of server-side language and check the value of the HTTP header `REQUEST_URI` (or its equivalent).

In JavaScript, you can check `window.location`, but like I said, it's rather pointless.

Comment: So it would be something like putting an ajax call in the js which checks or validates on the server?